# Does html render after sending a header location redirect first at the top?

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a php file that I load after a user has successfully purchased a subscription to keep track of a purchase conversion using adwords conversion tracking. At which after it needs to redirect the user to the next appropriate page `/account/subscription/`

Originally I placed the `header("Location: /account/subscription/");` below the conversion tracking code which produced the `headers already sent` error. So now I placed it above the tracking code.

Since I know its good practice to send a `die()` after the header redirect in my thinking was to place it below the tracking code so that it does not kill the page before the page loads the html.

Even though the `header` redirect is at the top of the page will the HTML below it render before redirecting?

```
<?
header("Location: /account/subscription/");
?>

<!-- Event snippet for Example Purchase conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-************/**************',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
<?
die();
?>
```

Comment: Why would you output something to the client's browser in the same page?  He is gone...   If that gtag is for google analytics, the browser will not run it anyway since it will receive a 301.  So tag the page before and the page after.  Let me know if I'm out in left field!

Comment: I still think even though it will redirect the html will load first though

Answer (score 1):

No.

The body of a redirect response will only be used if the redirect isn't followed silently.

I'm not aware of any *common* web browser which doesn't silently follow redirects. I think [lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) can be configured to do otherwise.

---

The general practice to `die()` is for cases where you are conditionally redirecting and want to avoid doing additional processing or including any HTML that is not appropriate for a redirect message.

Comment: so even with placing the `die()` after the html the previous html wouldn't be classified as `additional processing`?

Comment: It doesn't die until you tell it to. So the HTML would be output and included in the response. The browser would then ignore it because it was silently following the redirect.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this so that I can load the html before redirecting the user?

Comment: You can put the tracking on the HTML page the visitor was on before they made the request that you are redirecting to /account/subscription/ or you can put it on /account/subscription/ itself. (You could also do a non-HTTP redirect, which would be very slow and screw up the back button, so don't do that).

Comment: ugh issue is that I redirect the same way to this page from the `/account/subscription/` page as well

Comment: wait sorry Im wrong. I POST from `/account/subscription/` to a php file that process the credit card and upon successful I then redirect to the conversion tracking page (the one I listed). I can't place the conversion tracking html on that php page because it screws up the processing

Answer (score 1):

Although this post is old I thought this might be helpful. The below work just fine as html will still get rendered

```
<?php
header("Refresh: 0.5; url=http://example.com");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

you tracking code here in body
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to redirect, before you add the header part, you must include another part `ob_start();`, which enabled object buffering so it does not send a header until the page is fully loaded. To complete:
EDIT: I realize now that this is not what you want to achieve. I do not believe it can be done in pure PHP

```
<?
ob_start();
?>

<!-- Event snippet for Example Purchase conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
  'send_to': 'AW-************/**************',
  'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
<?php
header("Location: /account/subscription/");
?>
```

Comment: Where is the `ob_start();` in your example? Should I clean up the `ob_start();` with `ob_get_clean();` after?

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Comment: Usually `ob_get_clean();` is not necessary, unless you want to do something with the output of code in the object buffer

Comment: Then no, using `ob_get_clean();` is not necessary

Comment: "In order to redirect, before you add the header part, you must include another part ob_start();, which enabled object buffering so it does not send a header until the page is fully loaded" — That isn't true. You can simply not send any content before you call the header function instead. This also doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: you cant send a header after html

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I believe I have fixed my answer.

Comment: This answer still doesn't address the question that was asked at all.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see what you mean. You need it to render the page for the tracking, and then redirect. I don't believe it can be done with php sadly

Comment: Actually, I think this can be achieved by sending a GET request to the page that conversion tracking. This can be done with cURL and `file_get_contents();` (if needed)